ADLS Gen2 operation failed: Operation returned an invalid status code Conflict. Account: 'x' endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete
Currently setting up a storage account for a synapse analytics workspace, there is an existing synapse workspace with a linked service to an azure storage account, When I tried to setup a similar configuration I get the error message below.
ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'. Account: 'xxx'. ErrorCode: 'EndpointUnsupportedAccountFeatures'. Message: 'This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.'. RequestId: 'x'. 
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

If I disable soft delete for containers and blobs, the test connection functionality works, but the moment I enable it, it fails.
What worries me is this, within one of our other environments soft delete for containers and blobs is enabled and the connection works, setup with a managed identity, this was done over a year ago, but If I try to do that today with a new configuration it doesnt work. Not sure what i am supposed to do here.

different storage account similar configuration.

